# "Missing Context for method declaration" with the constructor

Tags: objective-c

Im getting only this failure after having built the project.
Im using the XCode 4.6.3

class.m

```
#import "Car.h"
//constructor
-(id)init          //<----- ***MISSING CONTEXT FOR METHOD DECLARATION***
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.brand = @"";
        self.model = @"";
        self.vin = 0;
    }
    return self;
```

class.h contains no error.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject
{
    NSString *brand, *model;
    NSNumber *vin;
}
    //set
-(void) setBrand:(NSString *) newBrand;
-(void) setModel:(NSString *) newModel;
-(void) setVIN:(NSNumber *) newVIN;
    //get
-(NSString *) getBrand;
-(NSString *) getModel;
-(NSNumber *) getVIN;
    //methods
-(void) accelerateTo100;
-(void) fuelConsuming;
-(void) hardStop;
@end
```

Can you help me with this. Thanks alot.

Comment: I've fully override all methods in the Class.m. The problem with the constructor is the last remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is what @CodaFi explained. Try this

```
#import "Car.h"
@implementation Car

-(id)init          
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){

        [self setBrand : @""];
        [self setMode1 : @""];
        [self setVIN : @""];
          }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementations of methods related to the Car class are always wrapped in `@implementation Car` and terminated with an `@end`.  You're declaring and implementing methods without telling the compiler which class they belong to.

Comment: I often face with the common output "lldb" which is not really an error. I tried to rewrite all the exactly old code to the new project which performed the output as expected. So is there anyway to fix that "lldb"? plz give me a hint.

Comment: LLDB is not an error, or a log, it's the debugger itself.  It stops on exceptions and allows you to see and print variables in the current frame, as well as going up and down the call stack if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have an #import "..." within the @implementation section.